# C Not able to include a format specifier when assign a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, replace

I'd like to be able to use the %d format specifier when assign a value to a string called `answer`. I tried to do this but I can't get the format specifier replaced by an integer when running the program...
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                    
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                     
    const char *answer;                                                                                                                               
    int year;                                                                                                                                         
    printf("Enter a year: \n");                                                                                                                       
    scanf("%d", &year);                       
    if ( (year % 400 == 0) || ( (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0) ) ){                                                                            
        answer =  "%d does have a bissextus day", year;                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                 
    else {                                                                                                                                            
        answer = "%d doesn't have a bissextus day", year;                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                 

    printf("%s\n", answer);                                                                                                                           

    return 0;                                                                                                                                         
}
```

I'd also like to know if in this case it's a good choice to use `const char *answer` and if it's not, I'd like to know what I should use instead.

Comment: You need to use the `sprintf` function to print to a string. You cannot alter a constant string.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? Just change the `printf` to be: `printf("%d %s have a bissextus day", is_bissextus, year);` where `is_bissextus` is set to be `"does"` or `"doesn't"`by the `if` block.

Comment: @markgz: Never use `sprintf`; use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: Thanks @markgz 
But am I able to do what I intended to do using the `sprintf` function?

Comment: Thanks @kaylum ! That's a really nice idea

Comment: @NicolBolas Why's that??

Comment: @AndreKorol To avoid potential buffer overflow.

Comment: @AndreKorol: Because it's dangerously unsafe. It's a common vector for buffer overrun attacks. `snprintf` does the same thing, but you pass it the maximun size of the buffer, so it will not write more characters than that.

Comment: Thanks @tuple_cat ! Now I understand it

Comment: @NicolBolas so it's not safe for me to declare a string the way I was doing, right? Sorry for being sounding so lame, I really just started to code in C...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`snprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
char answer[34]; 
// ...                                                                                                                                                                               
snprintf(answer, 34, "%d does have a bissextus day", year);
```

Comment: Do I really have to set the size of answer? Isn't there another way to do it by not defining it's size?

Comment: @AndreKorol you can write `size_t n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d does have a bissextus day", year); char answer[n+1]; snprintf(answer, sizeof answer, "%d does have a bissextus day", year);`

Comment: With `sprintf` instead of `snprintf` you can leave out the size argument but then `sprintf` will write to the buffer regardless of whether there's is enough space for the string.

Comment: Thanks @M.M ! That's the kind of solution I like! haha Going to try this right now.

Comment: Thanks @tuple_cat ! Now I got it

Answer (score 0):

> answer =  "%d does have a bissextus day", year;

Here your storing string data in which %d formate specififer doesnt has any effect with int type year, your expecting it should print year. Something which in double quotes in C is treated as string with null termination in the end.

**Try this code, its just simple and straight forward:**

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                    
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){                                                                                                                                                     
    int year;                                                                                                                                         
    printf("Enter a year:");                                                                                                                       
    scanf("%d", &year);                       

    if ( (year % 400 == 0) || ( (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0) ) ){                                                                            
        printf("%d does have a bissextus day", year);                                                                                               
    } else {                                                                                                                                            
        printf("%d doesn't have a bissextus day", year);                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                 
    return 0;                                                                                                                                         
}
```

**Output :**

```
./a.exe
Enter a year:2017
2017 doesn't have a bissextus day
$  ./a.exe
Enter a year:2000
2000 does have a bissextus day
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @LethalProgrammer! I already know how to do that this way. I was just trying to do it in another way. But now I think I'm really just going to stick to the basics haha